# How to link collection view scroll to mapkit annotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mapkit

I'm building an app in swift that has a collection view and a map view on the same page. The user can scroll through the collection view to see offers (this is the purpose of the app) and the map view is populated with annotation pins displaying the physical location of the offers on the map.

My issue is that i'm finding it hard to link the collection view cell to the correct annotation. I use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {    

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[row], animated: true)
}
```

in order to link to the annotation. But the index path does not often link to the relevant annotation. I've read elsewhere on this site that the annotation indexes are not ordered and the users location data also messes up this order.

I'd like to be able to link the cell to the annotation but am at a loss on how to do this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you just showing a simple `MKPinAnnotation`? You can create your own annotation type and store `indexPath` there for later to match.

Comment: Hi, yes annotations are added using this code snippet.  for location in self.queryDataMapAnnotations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
            annotation.subtitle = location["distance"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, would you be able to point me in the right direction with your approach? I'm kind of new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about maintaining your own annotation objects and collectionView dataSources by yourself instead of reading it from `MKMapView`'s `annotations` property?

I'm guessing that the main problem is:

**The order of annotation object's of `MKMapView` is not same with the collectionView dataSource you use, so you will pick the wrong annotation object.**

Sorry I'm not quite familiar in Swift yet, I'll express my thought in Obj-C

I assume you have a bunch of instances of `Order` class stored in an array called `orders`

Declare an array to store annotation objects

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *annotations;`

Create annotations from your `Order` objects

```
for (Order *order in self.orders) {
    MKAnnotation *annotation = [[MKAnnotation alloc] init];
    [self.annotations addObject:annotation];
}
[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.annotations];
```

Remember to read your order objects from `orders` array for collectionView,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Order *order = [self.orders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.annotations[indexPath.row] animated:YES];
}
```

When you want to select your annotations, pick it from the `annotations` array.

This way, we can guarantee that when `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is called, the order of annotation objects and `Order` objects were same, because they were added in the same order.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I already do have my own annotation objects and collectionView dataSources. I think the problem is I can't find a way to select the annotation using anything other than 
self.mapView.annotations[row]. When i tried your approach I was forced to cast the swift version of you ObjC code to MKAnnotation and "I got an fatal error.

Comment: Could not cast value of type '_TtGCs29_NativeDictionaryStorageOwnerSSP__' (0x105018038) to 'MKAnnotation' (0x1a634f720).